# MYSQL - How would I Export tables specifying only certain fields?

Tags: database, mysql

How would I Export tables specifying only certain fields?

I am using mysql 5.0 - using either a sql command or mysqldump.

My table is X, and the fields I want to export are A,B,C

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT A,B,C
FROM X
INTO OUTFILE 'file name';
```

You need the FILE privilege to do this, and it won't overwrite files.

`INTO OUTFILE` has a bunch of options to it as well, such as `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY`, `FIELDS ESCAPED BY`, etc... that you may want to [look up in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

To produce a CSV file, you would do something like:

```
SELECT A,B,C
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM X;
```

To load the data back in from the file, use the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) command with the same options you used to dump it out.  For the CSV format above, that would be

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
INTO TABLE X
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using phpMyAdmin,

Run the query

> SELECT A,B,C FROM X

and there is an export option in the bottom of the result.

Answer (score 5):

`OUTFILE` doesn't produce you a SQL dump, neither `mysqldump` can operate on subset of columns.
But you can `create table temp_weeeee select ....`, export and drop it.

Answer (score 4):

Shell command

```
echo 'select field from db.table;' | mysql -u user -p password > output.txt
```

Comment: Perfect! Obviously it works with multiple fields also:  echo 'select column1, column2, column3 from database.table;' |  mysql -u user -ppassword > output.txt

Comment: Thanks for the shell command! This also includes the field name in the output. Is there any way it can be ommited?

Comment: @axil Use the `-N, --skip-column-names` option.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT col1, col2
  INTO OUTFILE '/filepath/export.txt'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM table;
```